# How can I change external monitor screen brightness via command line?

Tags: command-line, kde-connect

I want to change the screen brightness of an external monitor using command line, for kdeconnect.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "scale=2; $( xrandr --current --verbose | grep "Brightness:" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d $'\n' -f 1 ) +0.2" | bc |xargs -t xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness
```

Yea weird solution but it works for me

```
echo "scale=2; $( xrandr --current --verbose | grep "Brightness:" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -d $'\n' -f 1 ) - 0.2" | bc |xargs -t xrandr --output HDMI-0 --brightness
```

Try changing output via

```
xrandr --current --verbose | grep "Brightness:"
```

and `-f 2` to `1` or for multiple monitors as well